# JQuery right click contextmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm new to JQuery and I just want to have a rightclick contextmenu. I googled it and found sample code

This is the code I'm using.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rightclickarea').bind('contextmenu',function(e){
    var $cmenu = $(this).next();

    $('<div class="overlay"></div>').css({left : '0px', top : '0px',position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: '100%', zIndex: '100' }).click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $cmenu.hide();
    }).bind('contextmenu' , function(){
        return false;}).appendTo(document.body);
    $(this).next().css({ left: getLeftPosition(e), top: getTopPosition(e), zIndex: '101' }).show();

    return false;

     });

     $('.vmenu .first_li').live('click',function() {
        if( $(this).children().size() == 1 ) {
            //alert($(this).children().text());
            $('.vmenu').hide();
            $('.overlay').hide();
        }
     });

     $('.vmenu .inner_li span').live('click',function() {
            //alert($(this).text());
            $('.vmenu').hide();
            $('.overlay').hide();
     });


    $(".first_li , .sec_li, .inner_li span").hover(function () {
        $(this).css({backgroundColor : '#E0EDFE' , cursor : 'pointer'});
    if ( $(this).children().size() >0 )
            $(this).find('.inner_li').hide();   
            $(this).css({cursor : 'default'});
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).css('background-color' , '#fff' );
        $(this).find('.inner_li').hide();
    });        

});
```

My problem is when i rightclick everything works fine. But when i rightclick again nothing appears. I should do a middle leftclick and rightclick again if want the menu to appear again.
can anyone help to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you send me whole page so that I can run and debug it

Answer (score 0):

(Could you upload your code to jsfiddle.net?, so we can help you better)

Anyway, my advice is to use this plugin to do context-menus:
http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/

Hope this helps. Cheers